# Submit form after close popup using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, popup

Here is my code:

```
$("form#subscribe").submit(function(){
    $("#layer, #popup").fadeIn(400);
    return false;
});

$("#layer, .popup-close").click(function(){
    $("#layer, #popup").fadeOut(400);
    $("form#subscribe").submit();
});
```

What I want to achieve is to force form submition after popup closure (popup box displays just a "thank you message", should be similar functionality like there is with alert box). What should I change in current code. Currently it's just looping popup box opening without submiting form. I've tried:

```
$("form#subscribe").submit(return true);
```

and

```
$("form#subscribe").submit(true);
```

on popup close event without success.

JSFiddle link to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/JZf8n/

Comment: `$("form#subscribe").submit();` should work, provided the script is in the same document as the form.

Comment: You sure you called `submit()` once only when `ready()` ?

Comment: `$("form#subscribe").get(0).submit()`

Comment: It would be easier if you built a fiddle or show us your html. I want to test the code but that would mean I have to rebuild it out. With just the code here there could be many problems outside of the two jQuery functions.

Comment: Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZf8n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change button submit id, don't use as ID 'submit':

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Sign Up" />
```

Then fire js event like this (not jq attached handler):

```
$("#popup").fadeOut(400,function(){$('#subscribe').get(0).submit();});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JZf8n/2/)

Comment: Working smooth, althou I had to fix it a little:
$("#popup, #layer").fadeOut(400,function(){$('#subscribe').get(0).submit();});

Comment: @Andre this is not good as the callback of fadeOUT method will be fired twice, once for each element